# How to adjust grid columns?

Tags: html, css

Why is the grid-column size larger than the image itself? How can I make it so that the column takes only the size required to fit the image?
Thank you!!

[Image below⬇](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pryHu.jpg)

Here's the code.
//*Html*

```
<section class="section-gallery">
    <img class="gallery-img img-1" src="/source/images/img2.jpg" alt="food-1">
    <img class="gallery-img img-2" src="source/images/img1.jpg" alt="food-2">
    <img class="gallery-img img-3" src="source/images/img3.jpg" alt="food-3">
    <img class="gallery-img img-4" src="source/images/img1.jpg" alt="food-4">
</section>

//*Css*
.section-gallery{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
}

.gallery-img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 80%;
     filter: brightness(75%);
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm that you want to show each image completely? Or would using sizing of cover be good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe because your height is at 80% and you need to put it on auto and put object-fit cover to balance your photo. Let me know

```css
.section-gallery{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;  
}

.gallery-img{
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     filter: brightness(75%);
     object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-gallery">
    <img class="gallery-img img-1" src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/56959a22d9dab9ff41b2e3e1/master/w_1600%2Cc_limit/health-fitness-blogs-vitamin-g-1108-food-samples-germs_vg.jpg" alt="food-1">
    <img class="gallery-img img-2" src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/56959a22d9dab9ff41b2e3e1/master/w_1600%2Cc_limit/health-fitness-blogs-vitamin-g-1108-food-samples-germs_vg.jpg" alt="food-2">
    <img class="gallery-img img-3" src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/56959a22d9dab9ff41b2e3e1/master/w_1600%2Cc_limit/health-fitness-blogs-vitamin-g-1108-food-samples-germs_vg.jpg" alt="food-3">
    <img class="gallery-img img-4" src="https://media.glamour.com/photos/56959a22d9dab9ff41b2e3e1/master/w_1600%2Cc_limit/health-fitness-blogs-vitamin-g-1108-food-samples-germs_vg.jpg" alt="food-4">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your height is not 100%. If you fit the image you can add `object-fit: cover` or `object-fit: contain`

Like this

```
.gallery-img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     filter: brightness(75%);
}
```